# Get a date range only knowing the starting date and an interval, excluding certain days?

Tags: php, datetime, intervals

I need to get a list of dates that should range from the *current day*, up to the specified day (saturday, in this case) of the *following week*.

Example:

Today is `friday, august 1st 2014`, so it should get the dates starting from *today* up to `saturday, august 9th 2014`:

```
fri, 2014-08-01
sat, 2014-08-02
(sun excluded)
mon, 2014-08-04
tue, 2014-08-05
wed, 2014-08-06
thu, 2014-08-07
fri, 2014-08-08
sat, 2014-08-09
(sun excluded)
```

How can I go about this?

I was thinking on using the `DateInterval` class, this is what I've got so far:

```php
$now = date('Y-m-d');

$start = new DateTime($now);
$end = new DateTime($now);
$oneweek = new DateInterval('P1W');
$oneday = new DateInterval('P1D');

$days = array();

foreach(new DatePeriod($start, $oneday, $end->add($oneweek)) as $day) {
    $day_num = $day->format('N');
    if($day_num < 7) { 
        $days[$day->format('Y-m-d')] = 'valid date';
    }
}
```

It works fine for excluding the sundays, but it only goes up to 1 week after the current date, i.e. 7 days. So I was wondering if there was a way of making `$end` to be something like: *'the saturday of the following week'*.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a way to do that, if you take a look at the comments section of the [DatePeriod's Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php), you'll find an usage example of the [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class' [`createFromDateString`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php) static method, by *jkaatz at gmx dot de* (2009-07-10 01:55):

```php
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('last thursday of next month');
```

Using the same approach, you can construct a date interval by using the following string:

> *sunday of next week*

And it would let you get all the dates between the current day (including the current week's saturday) up to the next week's saturday (since `DatePeriod` *counts* up to, but not including, the *end* date).

You can find more information of the `createFromDateString`'s method on its manual pages, you can also find more on the syntax, keywords and notations for constructing interval strings on the [Relative Formats Manual pages](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php), which are also used by the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function and the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

Comment: I foundout that this static function is pretty memmory hungry, so beware.